# How Can I Query Polymorphic Relationship in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am able to create and even delete a polymorphic row from my app, but I can not for the life of me able to figure out how to query the relationship so I can update the row. My models and controller methods are below--all work except for `public function updateManifest($id)`.  I didn't include all the update code I've been trying over the past day and a half because it would be too much and not really relevant, but I can tell you that I can only get as deep as the `Workorder` model, I can't seem to query anything related through the poly relationship so I can query all the `manifest` objects.  Thank you.

**Workorder.php**

```
class Workorder extends Model
{
...
    public function manifest(){
        return $this->morphMany(Manifest::class, 'manifestable');
    }
}
```

**Manifest.php**

```
class Manifest extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $fillable = [
        'stream_id', 'manifest_number', 'manifest_quantity', 'manifest_rate',
        'manifest_total', 'manifestable_id', 'manifestable_type', 'stream_description_plus'
    ];

    public function manifestable(){
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

}
```

**edit.php (Workorder controller)**

```
   class Edit extends Component {


public function mount(Workorder $workorder, Manifest $manifest)
    {
        $this->workorder = $workorder;
        $this->manifest = $manifest->manifestable;
        $this->workorder_number = $workorder->workorder_number;
        $this->workorder_po_number = $workorder->workorder_po_number;
        $this->workorder_status = $workorder->workorder_status;
        $this->workorder_job_notes = $workorder->workorder_job_notes;
        $this->project_id = $workorder->project_id;
        $this->customer_id = $workorder->customer_id;
        $this->generator_id = $workorder->generator_id;
        $this->prevailing_wage = $workorder->prevailing_wage;
        $this->touched = false;
    }
    
        public function addManifest($id)
            {
                Manifest::create([
                    'workorder_id' => $this->workorder->id,
                    'stream_description_plus' => $this->stream_description_plus,
                    'manifest_number' => $this->manifest_number,
                    'manifest_quantity' => $this->manifest_quantity,
                    'manifest_rate' => $this->manifest_rate,
                    'manifestable_id' => $this->workorder->id,
                    'manifestable_type' => get_class($this->workorder)
                ]);
        
                return redirect()->route('admin.workorder.edit', $this->workorder->id);
            }
        
    
        public function updateManifest($id)
            {
                $record = Workorder::find($id);
               /* dd($record);*/
                $record->update([
                    'stream_description_plus' => $this->stream_description_plus,
                    'manifest_number' => $this->manifest_number,
                    'manifest_quantity' => $this->manifest_quantity,
                    'manifest_rate' => $this->manifest_rate,
                ]);
        
        
                return redirect()->route('admin.workorder.edit', $this->workorder->id);
            }
    
        
    
        public function deleteManifest($id)
            {
                $record = Manifest::findOrFail($id);
                $record->delete();
        
                return redirect()->route('admin.workorder.edit', $this->workorder->id);
            }
        
           public function render()
            {
                $items = Item::all();
                $users = User::all();
                $projects = Project::all();
                $generators = Generator::all();
                $customers = Customer::all();
                $personnel = Personnel::all();
                $streams = Stream::all();
        
                return view('livewire.admin.workorders.edit',
                    compact('items', 'projects', 'generators',
                        'customers', 'personnel', 'users', 'streams'));
            }
        }
```

**update form**

```
...
<form wire:submit.prevent="updateManifest({{$man->id}})" method="PUT">
    <div class="grid grid-cols-6 gap-6">
        <div class="col-span-6">
            <select wire:model="stream_id"
                    class="mt-1 form-select block w-full pl-3 pr-10 py-2 text-base leading-6 border-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline-blue focus:border-blue-300 sm:text-sm sm:leading-5">
                <option value="">
                    Select Waste Stream
                </option>
                @foreach($streams as $stream)
                    <option value="{{$stream->id}}">{{$stream->stream_description}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
            @error('stream_description')
                <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span>
            @enderror
        </div>
</form>
...
```

Comment: `$record = Workorder::find($id);` is giving you the workorder not the `manifest`. You can then get all the `manifests` with `$record->manifest;`. By the way the convention is to use the plural so you might want to change the method name to `manifests()` in the `Workorder` model.

Comment: @SASM that helped me with one respect.  I can view and even pass data back to update my model.  The only problem I am still having is when I open my update form, it doesn't show the filed values that are already in the database and if I don't fill anything out, it NULL's the field.  I can't seem to wrap my mind around how to `mount` the relationship to show current values.  I am updating my question with my current mount code.

Comment: I am not familiar with the livewire but can you try instead declaring the `public property` of the values you are trying send to view in the `render` method in the `Edit` class. Then assign those properties in the `mount`.